# how can I replace the URL on search engines with the business name?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, yoast

I'm building a site and I've noticed that when I search my site's name on google, unlike other sites my websites Url is displayed instead of the business title.

Can somebody please help me figure this out?

I've built my site using Wordpress and my SEO tool is Yoast

image for context:

[image: screenshot of a google search showing results for National Leak Pros]

Comment: SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question here first.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the quickest ways would be to update and verify your business profile on Google.

You can find out more here:
https://support.google.com/business/answer/3039617?hl=en#zippy=%2Cedit-your-own-business-profile%2Cbusiness-name